# What is the size of the following augmented matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Give the size of the augmented matrix corresponding to a system of $2$ equations in $3$ variables. (in the form $m \times n$)

So I know that a system of $2$ equations in $3$ variables would be something like

$x+3y+4z=12$ and 
$3x+6y+8y=36$

but since this is $m \times n$ and $m$ corresponds to columns and $n$ corresponds to rows would the size be $4 \times 2$?

Comment: It's the reverse: the augmented matrix is $2\times 4$. the first index is rows index.

Comment: my answer should be reversed even though the question asks for m by n?

Comment: The matrix of the given system of equations is $2\times 3$, not $3\times 2$, conventionally. So the answer is $2\times 4$ since you add one column.

Comment: does m represent columns or rows?

Comment: because n x m is conventional not m x n correct?

Comment: When  one writes ‘an $m\times n$ matrix’, $m$ is for rows and $n$ for columns.